# НЕ работает max-width в блоке .profile__content. Что делать и где я допустил ошибку?

Tags: html, css

```css
@import "sass-def/@imports";
@import "style";
// HEADER
.header {
  overflow: visible;
  background: none;
}
// PROFILE
.profile {
  margin-top: 55px;
  &__container {
    @include container;
  }

  &__start {
    text-align: center;
  }

  &__title {
    @include small-title($light-color);
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  &__exit {
    @include text($secondary-color);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  &__content {
    max-width: 396px;
    &_wrapper {
      @include flex;
    }

    &_title {
      width: 90%;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      color: $primary-color;
      background-color: $dark-bg-color;
      padding: 15px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      &::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 20px;
        left: 0;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-20px);
        background: linear-gradient(
          to left top,
          $dark-bg-color 50%,
          transparent 53%
        );
      }
      &::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 20px;
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(20px);
        background: linear-gradient(
          to right bottom,
          $dark-bg-color 50%,
          transparent 53%
        );
      }
    }
  }

  &__item {
    @include flex;
    &_container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      row-gap: 65px;
      margin-top: 53px;
    }

    &_title {
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: $light-color;
    }

    &_text {
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      color: $secondary-color;
    }

    &_prise {
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: $primary-color;
      margin-top: 19px;
    }
  }

  &__img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    &_wrapper {
      max-width: 164px;
      max-height: 163px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/profile.min.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header class="header">
        <div class="header__container">
          <div class="header__row">
            <div class="header__row_start">
              <div class="header__search_wrapper">
                <div class="header__burger_wrapper">
                  <label class="header__burger">
                    <span class="header__burger_item"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <label class="header__search">
                  <button class="header__search_btn">
                    <img
                      src="img/search.svg"
                      alt=""
                      class="header__search_ico"
                    />
                  </button>
                  <input
                    type="search"
                    class="header__search_input"
                    placeholder="Пошук"
                  />
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="header__logo_wrapper">
                <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="" class="header__logo" />
              </div>
              <div class="header__profile">
                <div class="header__lang_wrapper">
                  <label class="header__lang">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      class="header__lang_item"
                      name="lang"
                      checked
                    />
                    <p class="header__lang_text">UA</p>
                  </label>
                  <span class="header__lang_line"></span>
                  <label class="header__lang">
                    <input type="radio" class="header__lang_item" name="lang" />
                    <p class="header__lang_text">RU</p>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="header__user">
                  <a href="profile.html" class="header__user_link">
                    <img src="img/cart.svg" alt="" class="header__user_ico" />
                  </a>
                  <a href="login.html" class="header__user_link">
                    <img src="img/like.svg" alt="" class="header__user_ico" />
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <nav class="header__nav">
              <ul class="header__menu">
                <li class="header__menu_item header__menu_active">
                  <a href="#" class="header__menu_link">Категорія</a>
                </li>
                <li class="header__menu_item">
                  <a href="#" class="header__menu_link">Категорія</a>
                </li>
                <li class="header__menu_item">
                  <a href="#" class="header__menu_link">Категорія</a>
                </li>
                <li class="header__menu_item">
                  <a href="#" class="header__menu_link">Категорія</a>
                </li>
                <li class="header__menu_item">
                  <a href="#" class="header__menu_link">Категорія</a>
                </li>
                <li class="header__menu_item">
                  <a href="#" class="header__menu_link">Категорія</a>
                </li>
                <li class="header__menu_item">
                  <a href="#" class="header__menu_link">Категорія</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <main class="main">
        <section class="profile">
          <div class="profile__container">
            <div class="profile__start">
              <h2 class="profile__title">Профіль</h2>
              <a href="#" class="profile__exit">Вийти</a>
            </div>
            <div class="profile__content_wrapper">
              <div class="profile__content">
                <h3 class="profile__content_title">Історія замовлень</h3>
                <div class="profile__item_container">
                  <a href="card_open.html" class="profile__item">
                    <div class="profile__img_wrapper">
                      <img
                        src="img/yellow__hoodie.png"
                        alt=""
                        class="profile__img"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile__cta">
                      <h3 class="profile__item_title">Жовте худі</h3>
                      <p class="profile__item_text">худі, одяг</p>
                      <h2 class="profile__item_prise">1199.00 грн</h2>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <a href="card_open.html" class="profile__item">
                    <div class="profile__img_wrapper">
                      <img
                        src="img/yellow__hoodie.png"
                        alt=""
                        class="profile__img"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile__cta">
                      <h3 class="profile__item_title">Жовте худі</h3>
                      <p class="profile__item_text">худі, одяг</p>
                      <h2 class="profile__item_prise">1199.00 грн</h2>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <a href="card_open.html" class="profile__item">
                    <div class="profile__img_wrapper">
                      <img
                        src="img/yellow__hoodie.png"
                        alt=""
                        class="profile__img"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile__cta">
                      <h3 class="profile__item_title">Жовте худі</h3>
                      <p class="profile__item_text">худі, одяг</p>
                      <h2 class="profile__item_prise">1199.00 грн</h2>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="profile__content">
                <h3 class="profile__content_title">Обране</h3>
                <div class="profile__item_container">
                  <a href="card_open.html" class="profile__item">
                    <div class="profile__img_wrapper">
                      <img
                        src="img/white__tshirt.png"
                        alt=""
                        class="profile__img"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile__cta">
                      <h3 class="profile__item_title">Жовте худі</h3>
                      <p class="profile__item_text">худі, одяг</p>
                      <h2 class="profile__item_prise">1199.00 грн</h2>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <a href="card_open.html" class="profile__item">
                    <div class="profile__img_wrapper">
                      <img
                        src="img/white__tshirt.png"
                        alt=""
                        class="profile__img"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile__cta">
                      <h3 class="profile__item_title">Жовте худі</h3>
                      <p class="profile__item_text">худі, одяг</p>
                      <h2 class="profile__item_prise">1199.00 грн</h2>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <a href="card_open.html" class="profile__item">
                    <div class="profile__img_wrapper">
                      <img
                        src="img/white__tshirt.png"
                        alt=""
                        class="profile__img"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile__cta">
                      <h3 class="profile__item_title">Жовте худі</h3>
                      <p class="profile__item_text">худі, одяг</p>
                      <h2 class="profile__item_prise">1199.00 грн</h2>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
      <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer__container">
          <div class="footer__start">
            <div class="footer__logo_wrapper">
              <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="" class="footer__logo" />
            </div>
            <div class="footer__sm">
              <a href="#" class="footer__sm_item">
                <img src="img/telegram.svg" alt="" class="footer__sm_ico" />
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="footer__sm_item">
                <img src="img/insta.svg" alt="" class="footer__sm_ico" />
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <nav class="footer__menu">
            <ul class="footer__list">
              <li class="footer__list_item">
                <h3 class="footer__list_title">Інформація</h3>
              </li>
              <li class="footer__list_item">
                <a href="catalog.html" class="footer__list_link">Каталог</a>
              </li>
              <li class="footer__list_item">
                <a href="#" class="footer__list_link">Про нас</a>
              </li>
              <li class="footer__list_item">
                <a href="#" class="footer__list_link">Доставка і оплата</a>
              </li>
              <li class="footer__list_item">
                <a href="#" class="footer__list_link">Повернення</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="footer__list">
              <li class="footer__list_item">
                <h3 class="footer__list_title">Контакти</h3>
              </li>
              <li class="footer__list_item">
                <a href="catalog.html" class="footer__list_link">Каталог</a>
              </li>
              <li class="footer__list_item">
                <a href="#" class="footer__list_link">Про нас</a>
              </li>
              <li class="footer__list_item">
                <a href="#" class="footer__list_link">Доставка і оплата</a>
              </li>
              <li class="footer__list_item">
                <a href="#" class="footer__list_link">Повернення</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div class="footer__reg">
            <div class="footer__reg_start">
              <h3 class="footer__reg_title">Дізнавайся про новинки першим</h3>
              <p class="footer__reg_text">Отримуй від нас смс із сюрпризами</p>
            </div>
            <form class="footer__reg_form">
              <input
                type="email"
                name=""
                id=""
                class="footer__reg_input"
                placeholder="Email"
                required
              />
              <button class="footer__reg_btn">Відправити</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает" и замените SCSS на CSS, потому что в противном случае, это нельзя здесь воспроизвести.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1454512/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-media-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%85-important-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1/1454522#1454522